# Debugging ionic on android device cordova.js missing and window.LocalFileSystem undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a Ionic app on an android device using Chrome (I have tried the SDK "monitor" also).
I can't seem to get access to the filesystem on the device. I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource: file:///android_asset/www/platforms/windows/www/cordova.js
```

What I find strange is that it has "windows" in the path but maybe it meand nothing.

Also 
    window.LocalFileSystem 
is undefined all the time. 
I am thinking that is because it can't find the cordova.js file.
I have added Ionic.Platform.ready.

Does any one know what the solution could be?

Comment: If found the reason for the missing cordova.js file. Somebody had added 'www/platforms/windows/www/cordova.js' the in the index.html file.

Comment: The issue of window.LocalFileSystem being undefined remains. :(

Comment: It just started working all of a sudden. Don't know why. :|